# Can't explain Unexpected identifier error in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue in jquery where I am receiving an unexpected identifier error on my input tags. The code is meant to populate a template for a container and the error is occurring on every line where I try to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" data-field-name="label" class="form-control family_member_label save_on_change" placeholder="Enter a name" value="<%= this.model.get('label') %>">\
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong with the syntax to cause this identifier error?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery, only HTML. Please read provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, is that slash at the end of your HTML intentional or a typo?

Comment: `<%= this.model.get('label') %>` isn't JQuery. Is your template engine not rendering what it's supposed to? Or is the problem the tailing  `\\` at the end of that line of code?

Comment: the backslashes are there because I'm printing a multi-line string and the backslashes allow me to do that.